# Losing data variable on changing view in iOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios

I have a variable in my viewcontroller.h declared as

```
@property (nonatomic) uint size;
```

On the viewcontrooler.m, I set a value to this variable when a button is pressed.

The problem is, when I change a view and return back, the value of my variable is lost.

What can i do do solve that? I don't need to declare it as a global variable, because I just use it in the ViewController.m.

Comment: Please post some code, how do you assign this variable, and how do you go to the other view

Answer (score 3):

What I would do is on `viewWillDissapear` I would save the value with

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i", size] forKey:@"mySize"];
```

and I would just retrieve this value on viewWillAppear with

```
size = [[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"mySize"] intValue];
```

Then if you wants to delete the value from app just use:

```
[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] removeObjectForKey:@"mySize"];
```

One thing I would also try is declaring the property without non atomic (maybe you will retain the value between screens because of that!):

```
@property uint size;
```

Comment: But assuming the view controller itself isn't being deleted then storing/retriving the value would be a) pointless because it should be unnecessary b) more seriously it would be sweeping a problem  under the carpet, when it should be investigated why it happening, not to try to work around it.

Comment: Sometimes on the iOS device you cannot be sure that one of the ViewControllers that are not visible will be stored in memory. If there are any memory warnings system will release views that are not in view.

Comment: But we don't yet know enough about the posters code to know if the view controller is visible or not. We don't know if one view controller is displaying more than one view for example. Or what if the other view is being presented modally by this view controller. You're answer might be applicable IF the view controller is being deleted, but you don't know and neither do I because there is no info in the question to make that conclusion. If the poster is a beginner you will confuse him into thinking he should be storing to NSUserDefaults all the time.

Comment: Hi, I'm using storyboards. I read that by default, storyboards discard a view controller when you segue to a different view controller, and create a new instance when you go back. I'm a beginner. What the best choice to do? Thanks